# Android: how to put TTS inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, text-to-speech, progressdialog

I have been working for so long but still stucked.
The game has a TTS and it appears to require a long time to load (or actually is the code for the TTS correct??), so in view of the long waiting time (about 3 second when testing on real device), I would like to put a Progress Dialog (PD).

The PD has a looping circle. I code the TTS part as in the following code:

### AsyncTask:

```
private class MainFrameTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener
{
    private Index_game_card_intro mainFrame = null;  

    public MainFrameTask(Index_game_card_intro mainFrame)
    {  
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onCancelled() 
    {  
        stopProgressDialog();  
        super.onCancelled();  
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {           
        startProgressDialog(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {            
        // setup TTS part 1.1
          mTts = new TextToSpeech(Index_game_card_intro.this, this);  // TextToSpeech.OnInitListener



        return "Done!";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        stopProgressDialog();      
    }

 // setup TTS part 2    
    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) 
    {  
        Log.v(TAG, "Get completed message for the utteranceId " + utteranceId);  
        lastUtterance = Integer.parseInt(utteranceId);  
    }  

// setup TTS part 3 
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) 
    {  
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)  
        {  
            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);  // <====== set speech location
            mTts.setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);
            mTts.setPitch(1.0f);
            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)  
            {  
                // button_header.setEnabled(false);  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                // button_header.setEnabled(true);  
                mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);  
            }  
        }     
    }    
}
```

### Outside AsyncTask:

```
// setup TTS part 4 
    private void speakText()  
    {  
        lastUtterance++;  
        if(lastUtterance >= loveArray.length)  
        {  
            lastUtterance = 0;  
        }  
        Log.v(TAG, "the begin utterance is " + lastUtterance);  
        for(int i = lastUtterance; i < loveArray.length; i++)  
        {  
            params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, String.valueOf(i));  
            mTts.speak(loveArray[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);  
            mTts.playSilence(ttsilience, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        }  
    } 

    public void speak_action(String to_speak) 
    {
        // speaking
        // setup TTS part 1.2
        StringTokenizer loveTokens = new StringTokenizer(to_speak,",.");  
        int s = 0;  
        loveArray = new String[loveTokens.countTokens()];  
        while(loveTokens.hasMoreTokens())  
        {  
            loveArray[s++] = loveTokens.nextToken();  
        }  
        speakText();            
    }
```

### Trial:

I have tried to replace the code inside `doInBackground` with `Thread.sleep(1000);`. The PD works with circle looping perfectly.

### Question:

The PD is shown but is freezed, ie. the circle does not loop.
I would like to ask

1. whether TTS should be coded in this way (which does not actually requires `AsyncTask`?)
2. if need `AsyncTask`, how could the codes be rearranged?

I have googled but seem there is no one putting TTS inside `AsyncTask`. Would like to hear your advice... Thanks so much!

Comment: Most interactions with the TTS engine are asynchronous, so there is no need to put this code into an AsyncTask. That's what the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` is for. You should check out the sample in the SDK

Comment: but it really takes a long time for the activity to load up...without the TTS codes the activity can be loaded instantly...I mean, if then is that the TTS codes are missing something?

Comment: I can't see the code you put in your Activity, but creating a new instance of the TTS service should not cause slowness. Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) on adding TTS to an activity