# Wants to play a speech using TextToSpeech when Display an image

Tags: android

I have one problem about `TextToSpeech` in my project. Actually I am displaying an image in `GridView` one-by-one. Every image will display after two seconds. At the time of displaying an image it should be take the value of `int i of for loop` and play as a speech. But, it is not working properly. Sometimes it is play last two values of for loop iteration but sometimes it is not playing anything. Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

**PlayActivity.java**

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Intent intent;
private GridView gridView;
private int rangeFrom, rangeTo, counter, imageId=R.drawable.horse;
private String order;
private int i;
private ArrayList<Integer> imagesList;
private PlayCustomAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getStringExtra("rangeFrom") != null && intent.getStringExtra("rangeTo") != null) {
        rangeFrom = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("rangeFrom"));
        rangeTo = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("rangeTo"));
    }
    counter = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("counter"));
    order = intent.getStringExtra("order");


    gridView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter = new PlayCustomAdapter(imagesList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    new LoadImagesTask().execute();
}


private class PlayCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> imagesList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public PlayCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> imagesList)
    {
        this.imagesList = imagesList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return imagesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return imagesList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        ImageView iv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowview;
        rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_gridview_list, null);
        holder.iv = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.iv.setImageResource((int) getItem(position));
        return rowview;
    }
}

private class LoadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(PlayActivity.this, this);
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        try
        {
            if(order.equals("Forward")) {
                if (rangeFrom > 1)
                    for (i = 0; i < rangeFrom; i++)
                        publishProgress(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                for (i = rangeFrom; i < rangeTo; i++) {
                    publishProgress(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(i), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                }
            }
            else
                for(i = rangeTo; i >= rangeFrom; i--){
                    publishProgress(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(i), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        imagesList.add(values[0]);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result =textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            }
            else
            {
                textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(i), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

    private void speakOut() {

        textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(i), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most interactions with the TTS engine are asynchronous, so there is no need to put this code into an AsyncTask. That's what the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener is for. You should check out the sample in the SDK.

See: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.java

[Android: how to put TTS inside AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20471159/1447518)

Comment: Thanks Idan for sharing your thoughts but first I created TTS in PlayActivity only but it is just play in last iteration only. So, at final I put in AsynkTask. In this also it is just playing in last two to three iteration. I don't know what to do?